# Python3.3: Square-root optimization

Tags: python, optimization, python-3.x, square-root

Here the code on Python3.3:

```
import sys, re, math
str1 = str(sys.stdin.readlines())
Data = re.findall('\\b\\d+\\b', str1)

for i in reversed (Data):
    print('%.4f' % math.sqrt(float(i)))
```

as you can see, this program grabs data (multi-line random string) from input, and search for every digits this string contains.
After that just returns square root of every digit it finds.

Well, algorithm works, but not fast enough, and i have no idea how to optimize it.
Please help me with that. What i need to do to optimize code above?

Comment: By 'digits', do you mean numbers? Also, could you show us some sample input/output?

Comment: "but not fast enough" -- How large is the file you're working on?  How fast is it?  How fast do you need it to be?

Comment: How much input do you have? Did you profile to find the hotspot(s)?

Comment: Ofc. i mean 'numbers' :) sorry for that.
As example can serve every amount of numbers, separated with random amount of space characters and "new_line" symbols.
Data can contain hundreds of numbers, i need it working with hundreds of numbers, faster than 2 seconds.

And no, i didn't search for a hotspots.

Comment: I don't think your problem is math.sqrt.  You can compute hundreds of numbers very fast.  I computed and printed 10000 in less than two seconds.

Comment: What is the size of the file? Your code should be able to handle hundreds of numbers in the blink of an eye.

Comment: Does it have to be in reverse order? And why the strange `str(sys.stdin.readlines())`? That will be something like `['line1\n', 'line2\n]`

Comment: Is there an issue with directly parsing each line into integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a negative result.  I tried using a couple of tricks to make it faster, but it's only a little bit faster.

```
import sys, re, math

def find_numbers(f):
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            if word.isdigit():
                yield float(word)

lst = list(find_numbers(sys.stdin))
lst.reverse()
for x in lst:
    print('%.4f' % math.sqrt(x))
```

I thought reversing the list might be making it slow, but it didn't really make much difference when I just printed the numbers without reversing.

The fastest solution for Python would be to just run the above code in PyPy.

This is not a very difficult problem, and if you need speed, you might want to write a solution in C code.  C code will be about as fast as you can get for this problem.

Comment: If the common case is digits, try replacing `if word.isdigit()` with `try: yield int(word); except ValueError: pass`. I don't know why everyone is yielding floats since the only possible results are ints.

Comment: You can also memoize `math.sqrt` if repeated digits are expected.

Comment: That's solution works, thank you a lot!!!

it takes 1.85 seconds to work, which ofc. suits for my goals.

Comment: The key idea here was to collect the numbers only.  Your original code collected all the input lines in a list, then turned that list into a big string, then used `re.findall()` to collect a list of sub-strings, then converted that to a list of numbers.  This code makes a generator that finds numbers, then converts each number string to a number and yields it; then a list is built of only the square root values.  For me this wasn't much faster than your version, but I think I have lots of RAM in my computer and you have less, or maybe my RAM is faster or something.

Answer (score 2):

You can try loading and processing the file with Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
for i in reversed(np.fromfile(sys.stdin, sep=' ')**0.5):
    print i
```

As a high-performance numeric library for Python, I'd expect it to be the fastest solution available to you.

Comment: Seems to be about twice as fast as my Python solution or the original solution.

Comment: need to work python 3.3
as i know numpy still not in python3.x

Comment: It is working in Python 3 now: http://www.scipy.org/FAQ#head-288204f886c0a120754d189f434864554a4a970d and e.g. [win32-superpack-python3.3.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.7.0/numpy-1.7.0-win32-superpack-python3.3.exe/download)

Answer (score 1):

You asked for Python, but this can be done pretty well in C.  This C program does not reverse the numbers, but you can simply pipe the output through the `tac` program, which is like `cat` but reverses the lines.

In my tests this is about 3x the speed of the NumPy solution, and about 6x the speed of my Python solution or the original solution.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    char ch;
    float f;
    int i, n;

    for (i = 0;;)
    {
        ch = getchar();

        if (i > sizeof(buf))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "number too long!\n");
            return 1;
        }

        if (isspace(ch) || EOF == ch)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                buf[i] = '\0';
                n = atoi(buf);
                f = sqrtf(n);
                printf("%0.4f\n", f);
                i = 0;
            }

            if (EOF == ch)
                return 0;

            continue;
        }

        buf[i++] = ch;
    }
}
```

Comment: You *should* be able to simply use `scanf` to get each of the numbers without mucking with all the `isspace` business. (`while(scanf("%d", &i) == 1) printf("%0.4f\n", sqrtf(i));`)

Comment: i know how to solve it in C/C++, but i was needed python 3.3.
anyway thanks for a help :)))

Comment: @nneonneo, sometimes when you are tired you just write what you know!  I've written little state machines like this a bunch of times.  But yeah, the `scanf()` solution is easier!

Comment: How daring to provide a C solution for a python question. +1 for out-of-the-box thinking. :-)

Comment: @cfi, I love Python and would use it for everything if I could.  But there are times when C is a good tool for the job! :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Apologies for posting a duplicate of [steveha's much earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14997388/923794). Speaks volumes about my reading skills. Still leaving this answer online for now, just because of my musings about the i/o/buffering/runtime effects.

**Original post:**

I cannot believe that it takes Python longer to apply one regular expression, and calculate one square root, than it does take to read one line from standard input and output a result on standard output (or any I/O for that matter).

Since I/O at one point in time will come from a hardrive and will either go to another hardrive or to a user's eye, that should be the limiting factor.

I/O is usually buffered for speedup. Usually a buffer is filled in bursts, then the cpu idles while waiting for the device to provide more data.

That leads to a generator for your application. Write a generator that reads input line by line and immediate provides a sqrt number on demand. I doubt that this will be any slower than the overall I/O speed on any reasonable modern hardware. If you're on a special device (like embedded, uController, Raspberry Pi, etc let us know)

The one optimization you can do is precompile the regular expression. As you're using the same regexp for each test, let's do the parsing of the regexp only once. Your example in the question is fine because you're doing a `re.findall()`. I'm just elaborating for other readers.

```
import sys, re, math

pattern = re.compile(r'\b\d+\b')

def fh_numbers_to_sqrt(fh):
    for line in fh:
        for i in re.findall(pattern, line):
            yield math.sqrt(float(i))

numbers_g = fh_numbers_to_sqrt(sys.stdin)
for num in numbers_g:
    print('%.4f' % num)
```

This allows all the regexp and math operations to interleave with the I/O times.

Now, the one thing we simply cannot really optimize and integrate is the `reverse`. The algorithm must wait until the last element to be able to reverse.

So we could change the calling code to:

```
numbers_g = fh_numbers_to_sqrt(sys.stdin)
for num in reverse(list(numbers_g)):
    print('%.4f' % num)
```

And hope that this is faster what you originally had.
Again, the only reason why this should be faster is because we've hidden the runtime of regexp parsing and calculation within the wall clock time it takes to read data from standard input. This should still be I/O limited. Actually the `reverse` might not really add to overall runtime, because it just might interleave with the I/O happening on standard output. Looking at a wall clock, this algorithm might use up no time at all. :-)

To prove or negate my whole post, you could measure with `time.time()` how long it takes from the start of your script to just before the line `Data = re.findall`, and from then on to the end. If I'm correct then the data reading will take most of the time. If not, it's worthwhile to measure also the time required for all the regular expression searches. Let us know. I'm curious...

Comment: +1 for all the explanation.  I have to think that what was slowing down the original code was the needless building of big things in memory: first a list of all input lines, then a string representing that list, then another list of string numbers... it's definitely better to parse text as you go, throwing away text after it's parsed, and keeping only the numbers.  That's why a generator is the way to go, and you did a better job of explaining that than I did.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys, re, math
str1 = str(sys.stdin.readlines())
Data = re.findall('\\b\\d+\\b', str1)

d2 = [round(math.sqrt(float(i)),4) for i in reversed (Data)]

for i in d2:
    print(i)
```